# Arduino Mega 2560 connection with a CAN bus shield (SparkFun)

Tags: arduino

I am trying to connect an [Arduino Mega2560](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_compatibles#Official_Arduino_versions) with the [CAN bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) from [SparkFun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SparkFun_Electronics) and communicate. How do I go about it?

Comment: Muzab, what have you tried? What are the symptoms? What CAN device are you trying to connect to?

Comment: What code have you used to: setup input/output ports on the Arduino, setup/initialise the CAN shield, trying to send out CAN frames, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You connect the CAN device to your shield (connecting the [CAN-Low](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Layers) and [CAN-High](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Layers) signals correctly) and put at least one resistor of 120 ohm between the CAN low and CAN high signals (they are sometimes called terminating resistors, but they primarily [act as pull-together resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/what-does-this-can-bus-waveform-mean/19390#19390) (similar to pull-up resistors for open-collector/open-drain)).

Comment: Peter, Thanks for the post. I am still trying to initialize the Can shield to arduino. I have a D-sUB9 female terminated with 120 Ohm Resistor which i can connect to the shield and these two will go on to Arduino. Will the borad get the required voltage? I need to test this with a basic LED Program. I will get back to you after i go through the documentation

Comment: @Muzab: note that it is not possible to blindly send out CAN messages (e.g. for testing) without an actual CAN device on the CAN bus (e.g. as it is possible for, say, RS-232).

Comment: Board voltage: I do not know this shield, but usually there is a choice between powering from the CAN bus or from the Arduino.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep your suggestions on these boards and get back!